# Specify language in Octokit.net for Gist

Tags: c#, octokit.net

I am attempting to create a new NewGist using [Octokit.net](http://github.com/octokit/octokit.net) however I can't seem to find a way to specify a  language (Text, C#, C++, Java, etc) so whenever it is created it simply creates it as Text.

Am I missing something or is there no functionality with this API to specify it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a test that I just carried out, it looks as though the language for a file contained with a gist is being inferred from the extension of the filename.

For example, I just created a gist using octokit which contained a filename of install.ps1.  On checking the created gist, the language dropdown was already pre-selected with PowerShell.